# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT with server app and billing enabled

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I use calls like

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Switzerland+Bern+&components=country:CH&sensor=false
```

to get geocoodinates. This works for some hours an after that there is a response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse> <status>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT</status> </GeocodeResponse>
```

I am pretty shure that I dont exceed 2500 calls I can make with my server api key and in the API Konsole I only have reached 10% of my quota.

I even have billing enabled. Is there a way to debug this further or is there something I am missing?

This is my API Konsole:

[image]

This is the usage data

[image]

Comment: Does your server have a dedicated IP?

Comment: Yes it has. Its starts with 83.125. (the first one in the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. From research I understand the geocoder has a request limit of 2,500 per day and 20 per second. These are on an IP address basis.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index#Limits

That means if your application is on a shared server, and there are other applications sharing the IP address and using the geocode service, their requests will be bundled with yours to provide the total.

I do not know of any way of seeing the request report for the geocoder, the report in the API console is for Maps, which is for displaying a map not for geocoding an address.

As far as I'm aware, there does not seem to be any way round the geocoder limit, simply having a standard paid API account does not seem to make any difference to the request limit.

Maps for Business accounts however allow a usage limit of up to 100,000 requests per day.

The best option may be for you to change the architecture of your application (if possible) from server side geocoding to client side geocoding, which would negate the restriction on your servers IP. See https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with Google. Try to avoid server side geocode. Instead use a client side geocode.