# cURL Geocode OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I have a problem with google's geocoding api:

I have an address which should be converted to latitude and longitude by google geocoding api using cURL. You will see my code below. It worked fine, however suddenly it stopped working and I got an "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" answer. I looked it up and it normally happens if api is requested more than 2500 times a day. This is impossible, because my website is just upon finishing and has about 20-40 geocode requests per day.

So what is really the problem that "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" occurs? Is something wrong with my code that somehow google blocks it?!

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);

$CookiePath = 'mycookiepath/geocookie.txt';
$userAgent = "mysite.com";
$ListURLRoot = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
$ListURLSuffix = '&sensor=false';
$Curl_Obj = curl_init(); // Setup cURL
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $CookiePath);
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 



$stAddr = str_replace(' ','+', $ast);
$City = str_replace(' ','+', $ac);
$address = "$stAddr,+$City,+{$aco},+{$ap}";
$address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);
$ListURL = "{$ListURLRoot}?address=$address$ListURLSuffix";
curl_setopt ($Curl_Obj, CURLOPT_URL, $ListURL);
$output = curl_exec ($Curl_Obj);
GetLocation($output);

function GetLocation($output)  {
    global $db_connect;
    $Loc = json_decode($output, true);
    if(isset($Loc))  {
        $i = 1;
        while ($Loc['status']=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
            if ($i > 14) {
                echo "Geocode failed!";
                exit();
            }
            sleep(1);
            $i++;

        }
        if(isset($Loc['status']) && stristr($Loc['status'], 'OK'))  {
            if(isset($Loc['results'][0]['geometry']['location']))  {
                $Lat = $Loc['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
                $Lng = $Loc['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
            }
        }
        else {
            error_log($Loc['status'], 0);
            echo "Unknown error occured!";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a shared server (or one on RackSpace)?  You will also get this error if you geocode more than ~10 locations too quickly (hit the rate limit).

Comment: I dont know what either of those are (sorry:/). My Website is simple hosted by a webhoster (shared hosting?!). Yes but i didnt geocode so many at a time and I thought the sleep Method in my code would prevent that from happening?!

Comment: If it is a shared host and you don't use a server key, the quota / rate limit applies to all websites on that host.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OVER\_QUERY\_LIMIT with server app and billing enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575580/over-query-limit-with-server-app-and-billing-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it's a Google problem. Try to avoid server side geocodeing. Instead use a client side javascript solver.

Comment: But it is easier to use Server side geocoding Ehen i want to store lat and lng in a MySQL database.